# Cannot send json only x-www-form-urlencoded work with postman seding Laravel API endpoint

Tags: laravel, http, postman

Cannot send json only x-www-form-urlencoded work with postman sending to Laravel API endpoint. I've already chose body raw/application/json. And My body looks something like this:

```
 {
  "name" : "Diego"
 }
```

But my  $response->all() is empty.

Comment: Any errors in your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file?

Comment: Dumping something else from your method works? So you reach the controller using a POST method?